# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ognl/PropertyAccessor

Tags: struts2, ognl

I just tried to compile a simple hello java program on eclipse ide. An here is the stack trace. I added all the required libraries for struts 2.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ognl/PropertyAccessor
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:342)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! It would be great if you'd add the source code, or the snippet you tried to compile.

Comment: *I added all the required libraries for struts 2.*  - Apparently not.

Comment: You're either missing the dependency entirely, or have the wrong version(s).

Answer (score 10):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ognl</groupId>
    <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version> 
</dependency>
```

Add this in pom file. While using the thymeleaf starter in spring boot.

Comment: For future versions: This page is a good place to check the version of ognl:ognl used, among the Compile Dependencies. I found that even patch updates will break Thymeleaf for me https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.0.15.RELEASE

Answer (score 3):

You are missing Apache Commons OGNL framework libraries. You can download it from [Apache Commons OGNL page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/dependencies.html).

> Dependency Tree:
>
> ```
> org.apache.commons:commons-ognl:jar:4.0-SNAPSHOT Information
>     junit:junit:jar:4.10 (test) Information
>         org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1 (test) Information
>     org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.3 (test) Information
>     org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.16.1-GA (compile) Information
>     com.carrotsearch:junit-benchmarks:jar:jdk15:0.3.0 (test) Information
>     ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.2 (test) Information
>         javassist:javassist:jar:3.11.0.GA (test) Information
>     org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (test) Information
>     com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.158 (test) Information
> ```